# ggplot2 confusion

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi can anyone tell me whats wrong with following R code?

```
ggplot(train, aes(x= Item_Visibility, y = Item_Outlet_Sales)) + 
geom_point(size = 2.5, color="navy") + 
xlab("Item Visibility") + 
ylab("Item Outlet Sales") + 
ggtitle("Item Visibility vs Item Outlet Sales")
```

Comment: show me your data

Comment: train <- read.csv("Train_UWu5bXk.csv")
test<- read.csv("Test_u94Q5KV.csv")

Comment: Is that what you asked

Comment: What he asked was to add a working dataset.

Comment: how to add that?

Comment: how do i add "Train_UWu5bXk.csv"?

Comment: Use dput() and read  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: `train <- read.csv("Train_UWu5bXk.csv")` and then `dput(train)`

Comment: Also please decribe what "not working" means. Do you get an error message? A warning? What does it say? Does the code seem to run but there is not plot? Or does it produce a plot that is somehow different than you expect?

Comment: In addition to the link ed_sans shared, you should probably read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get the hang of using this site.

Comment: Okay thanks, I was about to write the error message

Comment: > + geom_point(size = 2.5, color="navy") 
Error in +geom_point(size = 2.5, color = "navy") : 
  invalid argument to unary operator
> + xlab("Item Visibility") 
Error in +xlab("Item Visibility") : invalid argument to unary operator
> + ylab("Item Outlet Sales") + ggtitle("Item Visibility vs Item Outlet Sales")
Error in +ylab("Item Outlet Sales") : invalid argument to unary operator

Comment: There is no plot due to these error messages

Comment: Train dataset is already loaded

Comment: The error message says  `Error in +geom_point(size = 2.5, color = "navy")`. Appararently, this line starts with a `+`. Make sure to put the `+` at the end of the previous line. Otherwise, R assumes that the `ggplot(...` line is complete and does not recognize that the next line is meant as a continuation line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong that I can see. Your code works. Some times such errors arise due to not flowing the ggplot expression properly. Try it like this:

```
ggplot(train, aes(x= Item_Visibility, y = Item_Outlet_Sales)) + geom_point(size = 2.5, color="navy") + xlab("Item Visibility") + ylab("Item Outlet Sales") + ggtitle("Item Visibility vs Item Outlet Sales")
```

Assuming you got the data from 
https://github.com/hannarud/r-plotting/blob/master/Train_UWu5bXk.csv

[image]

Comment: No problems. In future, please heed the advice about posting good questions in the other comments above. Also, pasting the error message from R into a search engine often gives you the answer right away! Have a read of this as well: https://www.r-project.org/help.html